# Api call to web server when deployed nginx

Tags: angular, api, nginx, deployment

I have a silly question. I am deploying angular +.NET Core app, thing is if I upload it and set all to be http, in order for it to work I must specify all calls in angular to start with domain address, and this way it connects. When I am in development my api calls start with localhost. Problem is After I nistalled SSL Certificate I can no longer connect to my server in deployment whatever prefix I use in Angular calls. How can I fix this?
When I use the app I get in browser this error: Failed to load resource: net::ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED
I have tried this combinations in angular calls but they don't fix the problem:

```
http.get('https://localhost:5020/categories/three')
http.get('http://localhost:5020/categories/three')
http.get('https://domain/categories/three')
http.get('/')

http.get('http://domain/categories/three') This used to work before SSL installation but not any more
```

The settings in nginx are as follows mydomain -> localhost 5020 on server then comes the automatic redirection settings for https and my angular app must point, to what so it can get its content from server?

Comment: And what about `http.get('https://domain/categories/three')`? Are there any messages in DevTools console?

Comment: GET https://domain.tk/categories/three 500 (Internal Server Error)

Comment: Is there something in the nginx error log?

Comment: Thank you, salution was as you proposed [ http.get('https://domain/categories/three') ], and also not starting my dotnet app via service so I can see the fireworks of turned off mysql :).